# JSON generation problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

This way i am trying to generate JSON but i am getting error.

```
var DTO =
        {
            "UserID": $('txtUserID').val(),
            "Pwd": $('txtPassword').val(),
            "isPersistent": $('#chkRemember').attr('checked')
        };
```

here this way i am sending json data to my server side function'

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var DTO =
        {
            "UserID": $('txtUserID').val(),
            "Pwd": $('txtPassword').val(),
            "isPersistent": $('#chkRemember').attr('checked')
        };

        alert(DTO);
        alert(JSON.stringify(DTO));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CateGory.aspx/GetData",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                sHtml = data.d;
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }

        });

        return false;
    })
});
```

am i making any mistake because i am sending multiple parameter to server side function.

### my server side function look like

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Authenticate(string UserID,string Pwd,bool isPersistent)
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

so please guide me that how to wrap up my multiple argument with data in DTO object and later we can issue `data: JSON.stringify(DTO)`.

Comment: Have you tried with `data: DTO`? I don't think that `JSON.stringify()` is necessary at all here.

Answer (score 0):

First: you don't need to stringify this. Second: Do a GET instead of a POST, because you have multiple arguments.

You can also create a new class:

```
class SomeObjectToBePosted {
    string UserID { get;set; }
    string Pwd { get;set; }
    bool isPersistant { get;set; }
}
```

And let that be the parameter for your WebMethod. Then you can use a POST again.

Comment: Why? Can't you send multiple parameters using `Post` method?

Comment: @Jan - Care to modify your answer?

Comment: You can post multiple parameters, but ASP.NET will throw them into one object, therefore if you create the `SomeObjectToBePosted` class, you can use that one; because it will be auto populated. If you just want the 3 params you have now, use GET.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

Using jQuery you don't need to stringify the data object, just write: data: DTO

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you `url` is wrong. I think you are calling a web service. And also you dont have to `stringify` the data because it is already well form `JSON`

Change

```
url: "CateGory.aspx/GetData",
data: JSON.stringify(DTO)
```

To

```
url: "CateGory.asmx/GetData",
data: DTO
```